# есть словарь, как пройтись в нем циклом что бы поменять значения на True?

Tags: python

есть словарь

```
 checks = {
        'file_path': False,
        'audioformat': False,
        'channel': False,
        'sample_rate': False,
        'bit_depth': False,
    }
```

как пройтись в нем циклом что бы поменять значения на True?

Answer (score 8):

вот так:

**вариант 1:**

```
for key in checks.keys():
    checks[key] = True
```

или пересобрав словарь так:

**вариант 2:**

```
checks = {key: True for key in checks.keys()}
```

**вариант 3:**

```
checks = dict.fromkeys(checks.keys(), True)
```

Comment: Если питон третий, то keys() можно не писать.

Comment: это да, но как-то привычка :))) вижу метод - использую :) хотя конечно я за компактность и лишнего лучше не писать